# Is it possible to return nothing with a non-void method if a certain condition is not met

Tags: java, methods, types, return

Is there a way of returning nothing (not even null) with a non-void method if a certain condition is not met, but return something of the method type (like "int" if method is "int") if that condition is met?

Now that I have seen the comments, I had read about Optional class but couldn't figure it out. So if I have something like an ArrayList method, how'd I do it?

```
static ArrayList<String> method() {
    if (true) {
        return ArrayList; }
    else {
        ? } //(equivalent of return nothing, not even null)
```

So it'd be something like this, but can you help with exact syntax?:

```
static Optional method() {
    if (true) {
        return ArrayList<String>; }
    else {
        Optional.empty() } //(equivalent of return nothing, not even null)
```

Okay, there was a comment below, let me post my recursive function. What I want here is in the first if statement, there is a print and a return statement. But at the end of the function there is a necessary return null and thus the function returns null. I want function to return what it prints, i.e. indices, so I can use it as an input somewhere else.

```
static ArrayList<String> connectionFinder(String linInit, String linFin, ArrayList<String> indices, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linArray) {
        if (linInit.equals(linFin)) {    //returns the indices list if linInit reaches linFin
            System.out.println(indices);
            return indices;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < linArray.size(); i++) {
            if (linArray.get(i).contains(linInit) && !indices.contains(i)) {     //checks which stations are exchange stations for linInit, and checks the index to prevent infinite recursion
                for (int j = 1; j < linArray.get(i).size(); j++) {
                    if (!linArray.get(i).get(j).equals(linInit)) {    //j starts from 1 so as to avoid the station name, and checks if the linInit is different to prevent infinite recursion
                        connectionFinder(linArray.get(i).get(j), linFin, add(indices, i), linArray);    //changes the linInit, and adds the index ( add(ArrayList,value) is a custom method that returns the ArrayList instead of a boolean -ArrayList.add(value) returns a boolean-)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        indices.remove(indices.size()-1);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Not really. But you can try the Optional class. It has been introduced for this use case exactly.

Comment: No, that's not possible. The closest you can get is throwing an exception if that condition is met and handle it in the caller.

Comment: typically, a method that returns a list would return an empty list if there was nothing to return.

Comment: In a comment you wrote "I need it to return nothing, i.e. pass". This doesn't make sense. Try to explain what you intend to happen __for the  caller__ (the one calling `method()` here) when they call `method()` and this nebulous thing you cooked up is supposed to happen. Should the app just exit?

Comment: @njzk2 but there is something to return, I edited my post accordingly. We have a recursive function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Recursion, issue with return statement, returning a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75847893/java-recursion-issue-with-return-statement-returning-a-certain-value)

Comment: Yes, there are options. Would it work for your caller if you return n empty list? That list contains nothing. Or do they need to distinguish between "an empty list" and "nothing (at all, not even a list)"? In the latter case consider returning `Optional<ArrayList>` as @Mar-Z suggested. I’s not exactly standard, so may confuse some, but if iit’s what you need, just make sure your Javadoc is clear about it.

Comment: doesn't look like your function should ever return anything at all. If you want a function that returns something in that case, you should create a separate function that calls your recursive function and passes a new arraylist for `indices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a separate function:

```
public static ArrayList<String> connectionFinder(String linInit, String linFin, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linArray) {
  ArrayList<String> indices = new ArrayList<>();
  connectionFinder(linInit, linFin, indices, linArray);
  return indices;
}
```

And your function, now as a void:

```
private static void connectionFinder(String linInit, String linFin, ArrayList<String> indices, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linArray) {
    if (linInit.equals(linFin)) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < linArray.size(); i++) {
        // Loop omitted for clarity
    }
    indices.remove(indices.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: thanks njzk2. Your suggestion is correct. But there was a problem (which I found a workaround), is that while the void method you wrote returns, but still the other recursions remove elements from ArrayList indices (line 8) despite returning. I found a workaround (I added 1000 "abcdef" strings to indices just before returning (under if) then deleted them (which now number less than 1000 as line 8 removed some of them) in the non-void method). But theoretically can this be handled here or should the method have been written differently from the start?

Comment: I'm not sure what your function, but what it looks like is that you should have a return value that indicates if the connection was found or not (can be a boolean, or an immutable copy of the successful list of indices), and a way to backtrack if that's not the case

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to return nothing from a non-void method. In most situations, it is best practice to throw an exception if returning a value would not make sense.

For example:

```
public void setCarValue(int value) {
    if (value < MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new CarException(String.format("Value may not be less than %d", MIN_VALUE));
    }
    this.value = value;
}
```